# for node js I'm running command node app.js (or) npm install in terminal it shows some error how to solve this error?

Tags: node.js

For any command I run in my terminal it shows this error

```
# npm install
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.2/bin/../pnpm-global/5/node_modules/node/bin/node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.2/bin/../pnpm-global/5/node_modules/node/bin/node)
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.2/bin/../pnpm-global/5/node_modules/node/bin/node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.2/bin/../pnpm-global/5/node_modules/node/bin/node)
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.2/bin/../pnpm-global/5/node_modules/node/bin/node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /root/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.2/bin/../pnpm-global/5/node_modules/node/bin/node)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but... root?

Comment: Looks like the version of libc included in your distribution is incompatible with the version of npm you're trying to use.

Comment: how to resolve this issue

Comment: what command i have run by solving this issue please reply

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.